# How to use an external GPU to train neural networks in Mathematica?

Tags: warning-messages, machine-learning, neural-networks, gpu

Taking steps in the uncharted territories of eGPUs, I have installed an [NVIDIA GeForce Titan Xp](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/products/10series/titan-xp/) GPU on an eGPU enclosure ([Mantiz MZ-02](https://mymantiz.com/products/mz-02-venus)) and have connected it to my laptop ([HP Spectre x360 - 15-bl075nr](http://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/hp-spectre-x360---15-bl075nr) running Windows 10) using Thunderbolt 3. It seems my machine recognizes the device (since the name of the GPU is correctly listed?!). However, when I want to train a neural network using the external GPU, it gives me the following error (the code is from Mathematica Documentation and is self-contained).

Input:

```
n = 1000;
trainingData = RandomReal[1, {n, 4}] -> RandomReal[1, {n, 4}];
net = NetChain[{8, Tanh, 2048, Tanh, 2048, Tanh, 4}];
AbsoluteTiming[
 trained = 
  NetTrain[net, trainingData, TargetDevice -> {"GPU", 2}, 
   MaxTrainingRounds -> 10]
 ]
```

Output Error:

```
NetTrain::badtrgdev: TargetDevice -> {GPU,2} could not be used, please ensure that you have a compatible NVIDIA graphics card and have installed the latest operating system drivers.
```

My laptop does have an internal GPU (GeForce 940MX) and when I change `TargetDevice -> {"GPU", 2}` to `TargetDevice -> {"GPU", 1}`, everything works fine. How can I address this error?

### Update

Good news, I was able to run the above code on a MacBook Pro (with Touch Bar) using my eGPU configuration. But when I run `` Needs["CUDALink`"] `` followed by `CUDAQ[]` to list all of my GPUs using `SystemInformation[]` the Mathematica kernel crashes on my laptop, so I am not able to ensure that it recognizes the GPU or not. But when I unplug the eGPU and restart Mathematica, `QUDAQ[]` returns `True`.

Comment: Give this a look: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1085633

Comment: Can you verify, which GPU index corresponds to your external GeForce?

Comment: I believe this functionality tells you which GPU index corresponds to which GPU (via Support): `Needs["MXNetLink\`"]; MXNetLink\`PackageScope\`getGPUInformation[]`

Comment: Also, I was told that the CUDALink and Neural Networks `TargetDevice -> "GPU"` are not related to one another, as such it is very strange that they seem to affect one another. What version of Mathematica are you using? 11.2 probably addressed many related problems.

Comment: Escape character, \ :P

Comment: @user6014, I found that strange too. I'm using Mathematica 11.2 on both devices. I ran your ``Needs["MXNetLink`"]; MXNetLink`PackageScope`getGPUInformation[]`` and the same kernel crash occurs, again, only when the eGPU is plugged in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the [NVIDIA Drivers Download page](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) and download and install the correct driver for your GPU and system.

Open a new Mathematica notebook and ensure that the GPUs can be detected. To do so, run `` Needs["CUDALink`"] `` and check if it works properly by executing `CUDAQ[]`. This might take about 10 minutes if you are executing it for the first time. If it collapses ONLY when your eGPU is plugged in, then it's because you don't have the right driver for your GPU. If it collapses with and without a GPU, then your paclets are messed up (easiest fix for me was FULLY uninstalling and reinstalling Mathematica by deleting the correct directories after uninstalling it ([see this page](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12473))). These steps are not necessary to run neural network related function, but so you can list *ALL* of your GPUs.

Now, run `SystemInformation[]` and navigate to `Links` and then to `CUDA` to make sure that Mathematica sees your GPU. The GPU number that you must use in `TargetDevice -> {"GPU", n}` in replacement for `n` is listed there. If your GPU shows up, you are good to go.

Extra: For those of you who might be interested the eGPU runs 350% times faster than the internal GPU and the eGPU is 1620% faster than the Core i7 CPU. These were calculated using the code in the question above.

Comment: I wonder if those specialized bitcoin miner cards like (https://bitshopusa.com/collections/frontpage/products/bitmain-antminer-d3) might even be faster for training a neural network(based on the limited understanding that the process of hashing is something that gpu's are good at).