# NetTrain with GPU crashed

Tags: neural-networks, gpu

I tried to run NetTrain with `TargetDevice->"GPU"`, and Mathematica crashed. I got the following message:

[image]

When I executed `CUDAQ[]` I got TRUE, and after `SystemInformation[]`, `Links`, `CUDA`, I can see that Mathematica sees my GPU (As was explained in [How to use an external GPU to train neural networks in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156062/how-to-use-an-external-gpu-to-train-neural-networks-in-mathematica)) .

What could be the problem ?

Thanks

Guy

Comment: Hi Guy, it would be best to email Wolfram support about this. GPU support is extremely hard for a non-professional to debug remotely! If you can boil it down to a single, small, minimum example that always breaks, and if GPU support works for you for a _different_ example, perhaps it's an issue with your usage and we can help you. However, if not, it's more than likely an issue we can't help you with.